# Run syntax check on all files before running PHP Unit

Tags: php, phpunit

I want to check the syntax (i.e. php -l) on all scripts before running the test using phpunit, and it fail there is no need to run phpunit.

Is it possible to integrate into one step process?

Comment: Most Continuous Deployment tools like Hudson/Jenkins or PHP Under Control provide the facility to do exactly this

Comment: Continuous Integration is the best option. The poor man's version is having a script that will execute both processes.

Comment: If there is no CI system available, you could achieve your goal with phing.

Answer (score 2):

Without additional tools, you can use this line to check all PHP files below the current directory and only execute `phpunit` if no syntax errors are found:

```
find . -type f -iname "*.php" -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 php -l && phpunit
```

You could set it up as an alias:

```
alias phpunitl='find . -type f -iname "*.php" -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 php -l && phpunit'
```

and then use `phpunitl` instead of `phpunit` (with the same parameters that you would use for phpunit)